# Is universe checked by the Ubuntu Security team?

Tags: package-management, security, repository

I have a generall question regarding the Ubuntu universe repository. Does anybody know if they are checked by Ubuntu Security Team? Will they move or delete packages if any problem is encountered especially security problem.

Thanks for help :)

---

I just want to know how much trust can I put in programs in Universe-Repositories. I do install only stuff from main. 
If a package in the Universe will be found as dangerous - will Ubuntu Team delete it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question interests me, and I'm trying to get another four reputation points, so I can upvote a useful answer I recently found here on ask Ubuntu... so I tried to find the answer:

The ones who maintain "Universe" are the [Masters of the Universe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/). On their mailing list there was a [discussion on security updates](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-motu/2014-August/007695.html) for Drupal, in August 2014. One [answer](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-motu/2014-August/007698.html) worth reading contained "This is a fundamental difference between main and universe" and "users can always opt to not install universe packages". So if this information is correct it pretty much answers your question, I would say.

Probably *Debian* has faster security updates over its whole set of packages, than *Ubuntu* has over it's *Universe* branch... so you might consider using that distribution instead, if you need (server) programs not included in Ubuntu "Main".